# String function in qweb template odoo

Tags: odoo, qweb

I want to show data with specific length in qweb template and more data would be replaced by ...

```
i.e Name = "Administrator"
```

and if I want to show only first five char then,

```
"Admin..."
```

I have google about this topic but no luck, and no such documentation related to that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do it using Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks, will check it.

Comment: You can do this in pure CSS: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: @Ludwik Trammer: Thanks it's working.

Comment: But in general scenario can we use any other string function in qweb template engine ?

Comment: Nice answer @Ludwik Trammer, that should be converted as the right answer of the question. But you can always use CSS in Qweb, don't you Emipro?? Do you mean out of Odoo?

Comment: how to convert comment as an answer ? @Ludwik Trammer deserv it.

Comment: I don't think you can "convert" a comment to an answer. One would need to create a separate answer. But I don't think my suggestion really answers the question - it provides an alternative solution instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a custom function on parser report class**

```
def cal_string(string):
    if len(string) >5
        val=string[:5]+'...' 
    else: 
        val=string
    return val
```

**Call the function into Qweb Template**

```
 <field t-esc="cal_string(string)" />
```

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Where is the parser report class?

Comment: You have to add it becuase without class we can create any method in odoo

Comment: how to pass value from qweb to function